# Using Completion Blocks, versus returning a variable - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, completionhandler

I am not sure if I am correctly utilizing functions in Swift.  I find that in the majority of functions I use completion blocks to return the desired variable, rather than directly returning it.  This seems wrong, but i am not sure.  Below I will highlight examples of code.

Function structure:
Usually use

```
func fetchObject(name: String!, completionHandler:@escaping (_ success: Array<NSManagedObject>?) -> Void) {
    let objArray = ["one", "two", "three", name] //NOTE THIS IS A SILLY FUNCTION EXAMPLE BUT GETS THE STRUCTURE POINT ACROSS
    completionHandler(objArray)
}
```

Do not use much:

```
fun fetchObject(name: String!) -> Array<String>{
    let objArray = ["one", "two", "three", name] //NOTE THIS IS A SILLY FUNCTION EXAMPLE BUT GETS THE STRUCTURE POINT ACROSS
    return objArray
}
```

How most of my functions look when calling the function:

```
fetchObjects(name: "example", completionHandler: {(data:Array<String>?) -> Void in
    print("Data: \(data)")
    if let objects = data {
        //UPDATE UI
    }


})
```

How they look without a completion block:

```
let objects = fetchObjects(name: "example")
//DO stuff to objects
```

The problem I am running into is that USUALLY whenever i call a function my code relies upon its valid return, therefore i use completion blocks ALMOST all the time.

Is it correct to use completion blocks this much? It feels wrong because I am hardly ever using functions to return any values

Comment: The concept of using completion handlers is fine. The whole point of the completion handlers is that they are meant to allow a function to execute asynchronously while providing some kind of callback to fire later when the function has finished. It's not a question of whether or not you are using completion handlers too frequently. Your use of completion handlers will usually be directly correlative to the number of tasks your program executes which need to be done asynchronously.

Comment: Hmmm this is very helpful, so I suppose I am fundamentally using them WRONG.  Rather I should be using return values and then checking if the return value is nil or not to populate my UI.  (For time sensitive functions obviously)

Comment: That's the idea. Just as an example, there are a few places where you would want to use asynchronous completion handlers in an iOS app: UI animation (e.g. `UIView.animate(withDuration:_:)` ), network calls (e.g. `URLRequest` or even `Data(contentsOf:)` ), perhaps CoreData operations (e.g. `NSManagedObjectContext.fetch(_:)` ), etc. Anything which has a processing time long enough to "freeze" the UI for a user in a way noticeable by humans.

Comment: So some of my uses do include CoreData Fetch, however it is a guaranteed small dataset (1-15) items.  Would best practice be to make it asynchronous still?  without the data the app is useless, synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: CoreData is actually extremely fast, enough so that I would feel comfortable performing fetches synchronously, especially with such a tiny dataset (1-15 items)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of using completion handlers is fine. The whole point of the completion handlers is that they are meant to allow a function to execute asynchronously while providing some kind of callback to fire later when the function has finished. It's not a question of whether or not you are using completion handlers too frequently. It's a question of how frequently you are performing asynchronous tasks. Your use of completion handlers will usually be directly correlative to the number of tasks your program executes which need to be done asynchronously.

Just as an example, there are a few places where you probably want to use asynchronous completion handlers in an iOS app:

UI animation (e.g. `UIView.animate(withDuration:animations:)` )

Network calls (e.g. `URLRequest` or `Data(contentsOf:options:)` )

CoreData operations (e.g. `NSManagedObjectContext.fetch(_:)` ) though often even this is fast enough to perform synchronously without a completion handler

and more

Anything which has a processing time long enough to "freeze" the UI for a user in a way noticeable by humans.

Your example function is definitely a case where a simple return value should suffice.

```
func fetchObject(name: String!, completionHandler: @escaping (_ success: Array<String>?) -> Void) {
    let objArray = ["one", "two", "three", name] //NOTE THIS IS A SILLY FUNCTION EXAMPLE BUT GETS THE STRUCTURE POINT ACROSS
    completionHandler(objArray)
}
```

could be converted to:

```
func fetchObject(name: String!) -> Array<String> {
    let objArray = ["one", "two", "three", name] //NOTE THIS IS A SILLY FUNCTION EXAMPLE BUT GETS THE STRUCTURE POINT ACROSS
    return objArray
}
```

These two functions result in exactly the same thing. They are just implemented slightly differently. A case where a completion handler would make (theoretical) sense would be if the function looked instead like this:

```
func fetchObject(name: String!, completionHandler: @escaping (_ success: Array<String>?) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
        let objArray = ["one", "two", "three", name] //NOTE THIS IS A SILLY FUNCTION EXAMPLE BUT GETS THE STRUCTURE POINT ACROSS
        completionHandler(objArray)
    })
}
```

Because the function uses a different thread, the use of a completion handler makes more sense since the function is no longer synchronous. So where before this would have been valid:

```
var result: Array<String> = Array<String>()
fetchObject(name: "name", completionHandler: { (otherResult) -> Void in
    result = otherResult ?? []
})
let first = result.first //first contains "one" when function is synchronous
//first contains nil when function is asynchronous (DispatchQueue)
```

If we perform the body of the function asynchronously then this would no longer be valid since `let first = result.first` will be executed before `result` is ever successfully assigned to `otherResult`.

Of course keep in mind that in the end it is entirely up to you. The benefit of completion handlers is their ability to execute asynchronously. In some cases if they are functionally unnecessary then it just adds unneeded verbosity. It does come up to personal preference, though, since clearly they can both be implemented to produce the exact same result.

Let me know if this makes sense. I can elaborate further upon request.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!